# Trying to use a gyro sensor and having issues

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, atmega328, accelerometer, gyroscope

My setup is Arduino Mega.

I have a gyro sensor that I'm trying to use to measure the acceleration or G force in X axis (forward movement).

So far I'm trying to figure a way to use the value of Acc or Ax (acceleration X axis) in an `if` statement in order to activate a relay.

I tried everything and the example file the supplier sent is so confusing.

Please help. I'm attaching the main code and the header file too!

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <JY901.h>
/*
Test on Uno R3.
JY901   UnoR3
TX <---> 0(Rx)
*/
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  //print received data. Data was received in serialEvent;
  Serial.print("Time:20");Serial.print(JY901.stcTime.ucYear);Serial.print("-");Serial.print(JY901.stcTime.ucMonth);Serial.print("-");Serial.print(JY901.stcTime.ucDay);
  Serial.print(" ");Serial.print(JY901.stcTime.ucHour);Serial.print(":");Serial.print(JY901.stcTime.ucMinute);Serial.print(":");Serial.println((float)JY901.stcTime.ucSecond+(float)JY901.stcTime.usMiliSecond/1000);
               
  Serial.print("Acc:");Serial.print((float)JY901.stcAcc.a[0]/32768*16);Serial.print(" ");Serial.print((float)JY901.stcAcc.a[1]/32768*16);Serial.print(" ");Serial.println((float)JY901.stcAcc.a[2]/32768*16);
  
  Serial.print("Gyro:");Serial.print((float)JY901.stcGyro.w[0]/32768*2000);Serial.print(" ");Serial.print((float)JY901.stcGyro.w[1]/32768*2000);Serial.print(" ");Serial.println((float)JY901.stcGyro.w[2]/32768*2000);
  
  Serial.print("Angle:");Serial.print((float)JY901.stcAngle.Angle[0]/32768*180);Serial.print(" ");Serial.print((float)JY901.stcAngle.Angle[1]/32768*180);Serial.print(" ");Serial.println((float)JY901.stcAngle.Angle[2]/32768*180);
  
  Serial.print("Mag:");Serial.print(JY901.stcMag.h[0]);Serial.print(" ");Serial.print(JY901.stcMag.h[1]);Serial.print(" ");Serial.println(JY901.stcMag.h[2]);
  
  Serial.print("Pressure:");Serial.print(JY901.stcPress.lPressure);Serial.print(" ");Serial.println((float)JY901.stcPress.lAltitude/100);
  
  Serial.print("DStatus:");Serial.print(JY901.stcDStatus.sDStatus[0]);Serial.print(" ");Serial.print(JY901.stcDStatus.sDStatus[1]);Serial.print(" ");Serial.print(JY901.stcDStatus.sDStatus[2]);Serial.print(" ");Serial.println(JY901.stcDStatus.sDStatus[3]);
  
  Serial.print("Longitude:");Serial.print(JY901.stcLonLat.lLon/10000000);Serial.print("Deg");Serial.print((double)(JY901.stcLonLat.lLon % 10000000)/1e5);Serial.print("m Lattitude:");
  Serial.print(JY901.stcLonLat.lLat/10000000);Serial.print("Deg");Serial.print((double)(JY901.stcLonLat.lLat % 10000000)/1e5);Serial.println("m");
  
  Serial.print("GPSHeight:");Serial.print((float)JY901.stcGPSV.sGPSHeight/10);Serial.print("m GPSYaw:");Serial.print((float)JY901.stcGPSV.sGPSYaw/10);Serial.print("Deg GPSV:");Serial.print((float)JY901.stcGPSV.lGPSVelocity/1000);Serial.println("km/h");
  
  Serial.println("");
  delay(500);
}

/*
  SerialEvent occurs whenever a new data comes in the
 hardware serial RX.  This routine is run between each
 time loop() runs, so using delay inside loop can delay
 response.  Multiple bytes of data may be available.
 */
void serialEvent() 
{
  while (Serial.available()) 
  {
    JY901.CopeSerialData(Serial.read()); //Call JY901 data cope function
  }
}
```

The header file:

```cpp
#ifndef JY901_h
#define JY901_h

#define SAVE        0x00
#define CALSW       0x01
#define RSW         0x02
#define RRATE       0x03
#define BAUD        0x04
#define AXOFFSET    0x05
#define AYOFFSET    0x06
#define AZOFFSET    0x07
#define GXOFFSET    0x08
#define GYOFFSET    0x09
#define GZOFFSET    0x0a
#define HXOFFSET    0x0b
#define HYOFFSET    0x0c
#define HZOFFSET    0x0d
#define D0MODE      0x0e
#define D1MODE      0x0f
#define D2MODE      0x10
#define D3MODE      0x11
#define D0PWMH      0x12
#define D1PWMH      0x13
#define D2PWMH      0x14
#define D3PWMH      0x15
#define D0PWMT      0x16
#define D1PWMT      0x17
#define D2PWMT      0x18
#define D3PWMT      0x19
#define IICADDR     0x1a
#define LEDOFF      0x1b
#define GPSBAUD     0x1c

#define YYMM                0x30
#define DDHH                0x31
#define MMSS                0x32
#define MS                  0x33
#define AX                  0x34
#define AY                  0x35
#define AZ                  0x36
#define GX                  0x37
#define GY                  0x38
#define GZ                  0x39
#define HX                  0x3a
#define HY                  0x3b
#define HZ                  0x3c            
#define Roll                0x3d
#define Pitch               0x3e
#define Yaw                 0x3f
#define TEMP                0x40
#define D0Status        0x41
#define D1Status        0x42
#define D2Status        0x43
#define D3Status        0x44
#define PressureL       0x45
#define PressureH       0x46
#define HeightL         0x47
#define HeightH         0x48
#define LonL                0x49
#define LonH                0x4a
#define LatL                0x4b
#define LatH                0x4c
#define GPSHeight   0x4d
#define GPSYAW      0x4e
#define GPSVL               0x4f
#define GPSVH               0x50
      
#define DIO_MODE_AIN 0
#define DIO_MODE_DIN 1
#define DIO_MODE_DOH 2
#define DIO_MODE_DOL 3
#define DIO_MODE_DOPWM 4
#define DIO_MODE_GPS 5      

struct STime
{
    unsigned char ucYear;
    unsigned char ucMonth;
    unsigned char ucDay;
    unsigned char ucHour;
    unsigned char ucMinute;
    unsigned char ucSecond;
    unsigned short usMiliSecond;
};
struct SAcc
{
    short a[3];
    short T;
};
struct SGyro
{
    short w[3];
    short T;
};
struct SAngle
{
    short Angle[3];
    short T;
};
struct SMag
{
    short h[3];
    short T;
};

struct SDStatus
{
    short sDStatus[4];
};

struct SPress
{
    long lPressure;
    long lAltitude;
};

struct SLonLat
{
    long lLon;
    long lLat;
};

struct SGPSV
{
    short sGPSHeight;
    short sGPSYaw;
    long lGPSVelocity;
};
class CJY901 
{
  public: 
    struct STime        stcTime;
    struct SAcc         stcAcc;
    struct SGyro        stcGyro;
    struct SAngle       stcAngle;
    struct SMag         stcMag;
    struct SDStatus     stcDStatus;
    struct SPress       stcPress;
    struct SLonLat      stcLonLat;
    struct SGPSV        stcGPSV;
    
    CJY901 (); 
    void StartIIC();
    void StartIIC(unsigned char ucAddr);
    void CopeSerialData(unsigned char ucData);
    short ReadWord(unsigned char ucAddr);
    void WriteWord(unsigned char ucAddr,short sData);
    void ReadData(unsigned char ucAddr,unsigned char ucLength,char chrData[]);
    void GetTime();
    void GetAcc();
    void GetGyro();
    void GetAngle();
    void GetMag();
    void GetPress();
    void GetDStatus();
    void GetLonLat();
    void GetGPSV();
    
  private: 
    unsigned char ucDevAddr; 
    void readRegisters(unsigned char deviceAddr,unsigned char addressToRead, unsigned char bytesToRead, char * dest);
    void writeRegister(unsigned char deviceAddr,unsigned char addressToWrite,unsigned char bytesToRead, char *dataToWrite);
};
extern CJY901 JY901;
#include <Wire.h>
#endif
```

Comment: why did you post this? ... is there a problem of some kind? ... do you have a question?

Comment: Gyro does not measure Acceleration like gravity.  Gyro measures rotation around an axis like a twist or rotation.  Maybe that is why your project is not working as you expect it to.

Comment: All your sketch do is print a lot of data, where is the code you said about "use the value of Acc or AX (acceleration X axis) in If function in order to activate a relay."? You said you want to "use the value of Acc", yet, there is a method shown in the header file `GetAcc();` that you never bother to try. Read the source code if document is confusing and come back with some tangible question.